# Java loading file from classpath vs file system, which is better?

Tags: java

Lets say I want to load an image, "img.gif", would it be better to load it from the .JAR, or load it from the harddrive? Which is more efficient(speed, and memory usage), or are they essentially equal? I understand that loading from the classpath may be more convenient, but I'm disregarding that.

Comment: I think disk would be "marginally" better, BUT, that would depend greatly on the compression level of the JAR. I think most of convenience comes from not losing your resources...

Comment: Loading from harddrive will be marginally faster as loading from classpath involves searching the existing loaded jars for file.

Comment: Premature optimization. Do whatever is easiest for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Loading from a resource packed inside the jar is usually better because you can guarantee that the resource is always going to be there.  Having the resource located somewhere else on the filesystem increases the chance that it could move or disappear.

Also having the resource inside the jar makes the jar more portable and available on different Operating Systems with different filesytems or on different machines with different folder structures.

I'm not sure if you would notice a speed difference eitherway.

Answer (score 2):

Smells of premature optimization, but a JAR file is a type of ZIP file that's written on a harddrive. Since reading the bytes off the harddrive directly avoids decompression it's probably faster. Of course, you should only need to read and decompress them once. Finally, images aren't typically compressible with LZW but jar provides additional advantages in terms of software deployment and maintenance.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer! I wasn't sure if loading multiple files from the classpath was something you should avoid. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Also, you must consider that when loading files onto a webpage JAR files load faster and function quicker because, they allow you to load all your files in a single HTTP transaction instead of opening new connections for each file.

Answer (score 0):

If this is part of some web application then you might like to put your GIF somewhere in your hard disks and then refer that path inside your code. This way, you may also provide some security. If you place it inside JAR it becomes the part of your application itself. Important is not to expose the location of your file, instead Write some wrapper class to stream this GIF file.

If it is a console application then it is good to keep it with application (as in JAR) to make your application portable.

Hope it helps.